# Why use threads in Ruby Event Machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, asynchronous, eventmachine

Since event machine is said to be an event based model async I/O library (like node.js) that is single-threaded and uses event loop to handle concurrent requests, is it really necessary to care about and use threading on the ruby application layer code (i.e rails controller when handling requests)?

I'm more used to node.js model where you actually just wrap your code inside the callback, and then everything is taken care of for you. (the select() system call to kqueue, epoll, etc that spawns new threads are handled in the lower level C++ implementation), and also, ECMAscript by its nature doesnt have threads anyway.

Recently I saw this piece of ruby code when trying to learn about Event Machine:

```
Thread = Thread.current
Thread.new{ 
   EM.run{ thread.wakeup }
}
# pause until reactor starts
Thread.stop
```

I'm just curious when threads are to be used in the event-based programming paradigm in ruby environment and what specific situation would require us to use them.

I know that ruby has threads built into the language (MRI green threads, JRuby JVM threads) so it may be tempting to use threads? However from my point of view, it kinds of defeats the whole purpose if you're actually not supposed to worry about them in the higher level application code since event based model pretty much is introduced to solve this problem.

Thanks. appreciate any answers/clarifications.

Comment: As a sidenote; be careful with your syntax. Using capitalization, you're effectively overwriting the `Thread` class with an instance of the `Thread` class. You would then no longer be able to call expected methods such as `new` like you're doing on `line 2` after `line 1`.

Answer (score 2):

While using EventMachine, you cannot have a cpu intensive task because the time you spend on your task is "taken away" from the reactor, I use threads when I know a task is going to:

- be blocking (you should never block the eventmachine thread)
- use more cpu than my average tasks

In these cases spawning the task in a separate thread allows it to do its job without preventing the reactor from doing its own work.

Another choice is to use fibers which is yet another different beast.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference between a thread and a state machine, as far as I'm aware, is that threads will take advantage of a multi-core processor to do true parallel processing, while a state machine processes everything in serial. The state machine, on the other hand, is easier to maintain data integrity with since you don't have to worry so much about race conditions.